# Why is my keyboard "raw" as opposed to "translated"?

Tags: keyboard, 18.04, xinput

I am trying to fix some keyboard problems, and I ran "xinput list" after reading up on enabling keyboards and such (just in case my keyboard wasn't enabled automatically for some reason), and I realized that my keyboard is listed as AT Raw Set 2 keyboard, when everybody else (that I've seen) has theirs listed as AT Translated Set 2 keyboard. I've searched Google and come up with nothing, so I would appreciate any answers as to what the difference is between the two. Thank you in advance :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### AT = IBM PC/AT (Advanced Technology)

This is what an IBM PC/AT looks like:

[image: IBM PC.jpg]

*Image credit: Wikipedia*

There are three types of IBM Keyboard scan code sets in the PC world:

- Set 1 IBM PC/XT (had one of those)
- Set 2 IBM PC/AT (yup had one of those too)
- Set 3 IBM PC/3270 (Has 24 function keys like IBM Mainframe, S/36, S/38 and AS/400 terminals).

---

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scancode):

For computers since the IBM PC AT, the keyboard controller on the motherboard translates AT (set 2) scancodes into XT (set 1) scancodes in so called translation mode.[3] This translation can be disabled in pass-through-mode, allowing the raw scancodes to be seen.[4] Therefore, whether a software developer will encounter AT scancodes or XT scancodes on a modern PC-compatible depends on how the keyboard is being accessed.

A compliant PS/2 keyboard can be told to send scancodes in set 1, 2 or 3.

Your question focuses on the IBM PC/AT as pictured above which BTW is a very nice mechanical keyboard that cost $300 in 1995 when I bought one for a Gateway Tower PC.

---